# Convert FLV to Mp3 with thumbnail

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm able to convert a flv to a mp3 in ffmpeg, but I'm not sure how I would add in a thumbnail of the video.

Currently have this to convert from flv to mp4

```
ffmpeg -i video.flv -acodec libmp3lame -metadata title=video -b:a 256 -f input.mp3
```

Would I then have to run that through ffmpeg again? with this command, or is there any way to use complex filters to achive this is one run?

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -i cover.jpg -map_metadata 0 -map 0 -map 1 output.mp3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i video.flv -i cover.jpg -map 0:a -map 1 -c:v copy -metadata title=video -b:a 256k out.mp3
```

Skip `-c:v copy` if cover image is other than a JPEG.

Comment: so no need if `-c:v copy` etc works on every other img format?

Comment: Since this is just a cover image, every other format will take up a lot more space.

Comment: will the `-c:v` work with mp3's? instead of `libmp3lame`?

Comment: ?? To copy the cover image from a MP3. Sure.